# Is it possible to use Rhino Mocks to stub a generic method where I don't care about the type?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

I have a method with the following signature that I'd like to stub:

```
async Task<T> MyMethod<T>(SomeClass, bool, string, string, string, params object[])
```

The generic type, T, is the type that we expect the method to return (data returned from the server is cast to type T). Note that it can't be inferred from parameters passed in; it has to be specified each time.

I need to create a stub for this method in Rhino Mocks, but it's expecting me to provide the generic type. I would like it to cater for calls with any type. I tried using `<object>`, but it then expects a call with that specific type.

I can see why this would be a problem, because calls to generic types are dealt with at compile-time, not run-time.

Thought it would be worth asking, though, just in case I'm missing a trick.

**Edit 1**

I should have included that for now I've implemented a workaround whereby I've wrapped my stub builder in a helper method that is itself a generic method.

The problem with this, though, is that I have to specify the type, and then only that type is catered for. The system under test may make several calls to the method that I'm stubbing, and I need a 'catch all' that caters for all types.

**Edit 2**

My improved workaround has been to not use Rhino Mocks at all. In stead, I'm using a mock class that implements the interface. This makes it easy to implement the generic method and return a default value (or one that's been set during construction). I'd still like to know if it's possible in Rhino Mocks though!

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the stub in a generic method, and just return a default  instance of the given type, like so:

```cs
static void SetUpAStub<T>() 
        where T : new()
{
    var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyInterface>();
    stub.Stub(i => i.MyMethod<T>(null, false, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty))
        .Return(new TaskFactory().StartNew( () => new T()));
}
```

Comment: This is what I've done as a temporary workaround, but the system under test may make several calls for different types, and each one will need to be stubbed so that it doesn't exception. This is why I need a 'catch all' stub. Sorry - should have included this in my question.